# Why does my three.js "grid" not adjust the square tile size correctly, when resized, but initially loads correctly?

Tags: javascript, three.js, background, grid, vite

I am trying to generate a responsive grid out of planes with a near 1:1 aspect ratio. Depending on the window size the number varies, but still restrained through some parameters (`minVerticalSquares` and `maxSquareSize`)

This works perfectly fine when loading the page initially, the almost 1:1 aspect ratio planes are facing towards the camera and are positioned and scaled (size) correctly. Also when resizing the window horizontally the number of tiles decreases, whenever the squares get straightened / compressed to much.

But as soon as I resize the window vertically the squares get straightened / compressed vertically and don't fill up the entire screen anymore (Keep in mind, when initially loading the site everything fits for every imaginable screen size). According to the console.log statement `BackgroundSquare Size: x: ? | y: ?` the squares still have a 1:1 ratio, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

```js
import '/htmlLib/ThreeJS/testPage/cubeWave.css';
import * as THREE from 'three';

function Vector2(x, y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

function calculateSquareAmount(minVerticalSquares = 15, maxSquareSize = 50)
{
    // vertical number of squares assuming capped at max size
    let verticalSquares = Math.ceil(window.innerHeight / maxSquareSize);
    // if too few squares capped at min squares
    verticalSquares = Math.max(verticalSquares, minVerticalSquares);

    let verticalSquareSize = window.innerHeight / verticalSquares;
    // now get number of horizontal "squares" (rounded because it should align)
    let horizontalSquares = Math.round(window.innerWidth / verticalSquareSize);

    return new Vector2(horizontalSquares, verticalSquares);
}

function setupNewBackgroundSquare(newSquare, squareSize, x, y)
{
    // Generate Mesh
    let geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(squareSize.x, squareSize.y, 1, 1);
    let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial
        ({
            color: 0xff0000,
            wireframe: true,
        });
    let squareMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    backgroundScene.add(squareMesh); // Add mesh to background scene  
    newSquare.mesh = squareMesh;

    // Set square position
    newSquare.mesh.position.x = x * squareSize.x + (squareSize.x / 2);
    newSquare.mesh.position.y = y * squareSize.y + (squareSize.y / 2);

    backgroundSquares.push(newSquare);
}

function fillBackgroundWithSquares()
{
    backgroundSquares = [];
    let squareAmount = calculateSquareAmount();
    let squareSize = new Vector2(window.innerWidth / squareAmount.x, window.innerHeight / squareAmount.y);
    // The print statements do not align with what is shown on screen 
    // (eg. the "squares" visibly arne't even close to a square anymore, 
    // even though the "BackgroundSquare Size: x:" states they are almost the same height as width)
    console.log("ScreenSize: x:" + window.innerWidth + " | y:" + window.innerHeight);
    console.log("BackgroundSquare Size: x:" + squareSize.x.toFixed(2) + " | y:" + squareSize.y.toFixed(2));
    console.log("BackgroundSquare Amount: x:" + squareAmount.x + " | y:" + squareAmount.y)

    // Create all the squares
    for (let y = 0; y < squareAmount.y; y += 1)
    {
        for (let x = 0; x < squareAmount.x; x += 1)
        {
            let square = new backgroundSquare()
            setupNewBackgroundSquare(square, squareSize, x, y)
        }
    }
}

function backgroundSquare()
{
    this.mesh;

    this.updateMesh = function ()
    {
        this.mesh.material.color.setHex(0x362453);
    }
}

// Create scene
const backgroundScene = new THREE.Scene();

// Setup background camera and canvas
const backgroundCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(0, window.innerWidth, 0, window.innerHeight, 0.1, 2)
backgroundCamera.position.z = 1;
const backgroundRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer
    ({
        canvas: document.querySelector('#background')
    });
backgroundRenderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
backgroundRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

// Create background squares
var backgroundSquares;
fillBackgroundWithSquares();

// Called each frame
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var latestWindowSize = new Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

function animate()
{
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    backgroundSquares.forEach(square =>
    {
        square.updateMesh();
    });

    windowResize();

    backgroundRenderer.render(backgroundScene, backgroundCamera); // Update background
}

function windowResize()
{
    // break if window has not been resized
    if ((latestWindowSize.x == window.innerWidth) && (latestWindowSize.y == window.innerHeight))
    {
        return;
    }
    latestWindowSize = new Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    // Remove and recreate background squares
    backgroundSquares.forEach(square =>
    {
        backgroundScene.remove(square.mesh);
    });
    fillBackgroundWithSquares()

    // Resize render region
    backgroundCamera.left = 0;
    backgroundCamera.right = window.innerWidth;
    backgroundCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    backgroundRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

animate()
```

```css
canvas {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chaos Cubes</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="background"></canvas>

    <script type="module" src="cubewave.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

*I didn't get the code snippet to work properly with three js, but the code "works" and doesn't throw any errors when implemented into a project. In case you don't want to create the project on your own PC, but want to better understand what my goal and problems are, here some screenshots:*

**ALT:** Fullscreen screenshot of freshly loaded page
[image: Fullscreen screenshot of freshly loaded page]

**ALT:** Resized browser window horizontally (here you can see the grid still lines up, but the individual squares aren't exactly squares) Everything fine until now
[image: Resized browser window horizontally (here you can see the grid still lines up, but the individual squares aren't exactly squares) Everything fine until now]

**ALT:** Here is my problem, resizing the browser window vertically leads to the squares getting compressed vertically, although the console.log still says their size is higher than it actually is
[image: Here is my problem, resizing the browser window vertically leads to the squares getting compressed vertically, although the console.log still says their size is higher than it actually is]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem inside the `windowResize()` function. I am `backgroundCamera.left` and `backgroundCamera.left`, but I forgot to do the same for `backgroundCamera.top` and `backgroundCamera.bottom`.

This also is the reason why initially everything works fine and the objects themself are sized correctly, its only the projection onto the canvas that stretches the squares. When implementing the camera all values are set, not just `width` and `height`: `OrthographicCamera(0, window.innerWidth, 0, window.innerHeight, ...)`